# vendor/autoload composer with codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, autoload

I have this project that needs to upload files to an aws s3 bucket.

I did not install codeigniter with composer originally.  But for this task I need it so I installed composer.  It installed fine and is in root directory of server.  My project is in the apache folder /var/www/html

In my file if I do require 'vendor/autoload.php' it does not work.  Even though in the servers root directory the vendor folder is there.

I read in CI4 composer is automatically loaded so I replaced the require line with:
use CodeIgniter\Config\AutoloadConfig;

still nothing?  This is annoying because everything is ready to go but it won't let me include the required autoload files?

Comment: What do you mean by « I require vendor/autoload »? You should not require it. What do you mean by « it does not work ». What is the error? You should have a look at : https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/concepts/autoloader.html

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error you are facing. "Still nothing" is not enough to identify the problem

Comment: The require statement was not finding the vendor/autoload file event though it existed.  This is what I meant.  However, I ended up just not trying to do it with composer and installing it by the zip file.  I got it working.  Thank you though